# MAMP installed and htdocs is set as localhost but can't see folder within localhost

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, localhost, mamp

I have set up MAMP on my windows 7 laptop and set the localhost to htdocs folder.
I have created a database and renamed the wp-config_sample.php as wp-config after I named the DB, username, and password within this file.

The appache server and MYSQL servers are turned on.
In the Chrome browser if I type in localhost/ the following is displayed:

```
index of/
test.php
```

but a wordpress folder within htdocs called testsite is not visible 
In the browser if I type in the localhost/MAMP/ the MAMP page is displayed correctly.
If I type in localhost:3306/testsite the following is displayed:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost sent an invalid response.
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

The MySQL port has been changed to 3306 which is free

If I type in localhost/testsite the following is displayed:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /testsite/ on this server.
```

Please let me know what other information I need to put in this post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the folder permission to view the folder in localhost

Run command `chmod *** /folder` to change the permission

@updated:

Then you should try adding such lines in host file.conf in Mamp

```
Alias /mytest/ "C:/mytest/" 

<Directory "C:/mytest/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require local
</Directory>
```

Comment: I am using windows and when I looked in the properties of the folder the admin and non-admin all have full control over the folder testsite and it's subfolders

Comment: Please try above solution

Comment: Sorry I am having difficultly locating host file.conf.

Comment: C:\MAMP\conf\apache\httpd.conf

Comment: I added the lines in the host file replacing C:/mytest/ with C:/MAMP/testsite but am still getting the same error messages as above.